# Unable to provide image names dynamically to {% static " in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, django, django-templates

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="item in itemslist">
     <img ng-src="{% static "img/new/item.imagename" %}" alt="" />
</div>
```

**item** - > is an object, below is the object definition

```
var firstItem = {};
firstItem.id = 0;
firstItem.name = "testfirstname";
firstItem.imagename = "cart.png";

var secondItem = {};
secondItem.id = 2;
secondItem.name = "testsecondname";
secondItem.imagename = "home.png";
```

**itemslist**- > [firstitem, seconditem]

In the runtime, **item.imagename** is not getting replaced by its value (cart.png). coming out of the iteration. The request still looks with the variable name (item.imagename) and not the value (cart.png).

> Page not found (404)
>   http://example.localhost.com:8000/static/img/new/item.imagename

How do I get this working?

Comment: item.image is image name or src? and do you have base url?

Comment: what is produce.image? shouldn't id be item.image? Besides binding is done through {{ }} and not {% %}

Comment: Its image name (e.g cart.png) and the base url is loaded from static ( http://example.localhost.com:8000/static)

Comment: @Dario, Are you suggesting me to use this instead ? <img ng-src="{{ static "img/new/produce.image" }}" alt="" />

Comment: I get template syntax error for it , 
TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: 
Could not parse the remainder: ' "img/new/item.image"' from 'static "img/new/item.image"'

Comment: I would write something like this: {{ static + 'img/new/' + item.image }}

Comment: @Dario , the `{% %}` notation is Django relevant and I think your comments and answer only make further confusion.

Comment: @thatzprem have you properly configured Django static files? Can you confirm that they work ok with a different file outside angular?  Is the file in place?

Comment: Have you read this doc ?? http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration.html

Comment: @Wtower - Yes, I did validate the file. Its in place.

Comment: If I could pass <img ng-src="{% static "img/new/cart.png" %}" alt="" /> I could see the image getting rendered but not with <img ng-src="{% static "img/new/item.image" %}" alt="" />
How do I dynamically replace the image name to ng-src through an iterator?

Comment: @thatzprem then it is still not clear to me why you want to use img.image and what exactly is this, I would recommend you to edit your OP and provide more information because as is it causes confusion.

Comment: No, it is clearer after your last edits, thanks. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which a page renders with Django is:

1. A request is made from the client (browser) to the server (ultimately Django).
2. Django matches a view using the url, and from the view renders the template in server.
3. The client gets the response and renders the page. At this stage, the client knows nothing about Django, its templating system etc.

Angular is a JS technology that operates client-side. It has absolutely no way to know about static files, Django templates etc.

Therefore, if you require to load an image in client-side, then you have to properly specify the url beforehands. Since you know the name, you need only to provide the rest of the url to angular.

To do that, you need to include `settings.STATIC_URL` to your context, and render it into a js variable in your template. This variable will travel through to client, and then in angular use it to properly build the url.

Be sure to take care of angular's security considerations about interpolation though, but that's a different matter entirely.

The server-client confusion is a common one when beginning web development.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for helping me get an understanding on the basics!! One quick question though, how does it harm generating the URL either on the client side or the server side? As long as I know the url path and the resource end point name, how does it matter me forming the URL on server or client?

Comment: @thatzprem you are welcome, glad to help. In essence the other answers were suggesting a similar approach but were ignoring the role of the static tag for django and your confusion with this. Well, it matters for angular and django: django knows your path from `settings.STATIC_URL` but that happens server-sde, you either have to provide this to angular, when angular renders client-side, or to redefine it in angular.

Comment: with reference to this link, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/  I was trying to follow the very similar one by adding {% load staticfiles %} in my HTML file to reference the 'static' path and there on appending the resource file name to the URL end point. But I agree with your point that Django & Angular are to operate independently.

Comment: @thatzprem you see, the issue is that at the time when Django renders your template and it comes to `{% static "img/new/item.imagename" %}`, it knows nothing about a js object called `item` and there is no way for it to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="item in items>
     <img ng-src="{{static + '/img/new/' + item.image}}" alt="" />
</div>
```

I consider static = base url, according to your comment

Comment: Are you familiar with Django's template system? Your answer is totally invalid.

Comment: No. I am not familiar with it. I just give answer to think as a normal html. if he is used Django's template system then may be syntax is different.you can edit my answer based on that.

Comment: As I said, your answer is totally invalid beyond salvation. What is even `static` for angular I wonder. How on earth did this ever get an upvote.

Comment: Jay Patel, it isn't Wtower's responsibility to make sure *your* answer works.

Comment: as I said in my answer, that he is defined static in his controller so we can directly used that. so static is scope variable here.

Comment: @Sayse, yes I know and if he edit anything I will check and test first before approve but needs to be clarify is good for other as well.

Comment: No, `static` is a django template tag, it isn't using Angular syntax here.

Comment: @Sayse - you are rite, static is a template tag. How do I dynamically replace the image name to ng-src through an iterator?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this issue in the future,

What ever you're static_url is in the django settings. For example:

```
STATIC_URL='/static/'
```

then in your template do this:

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="item in items>
     <img ng-src="static/img/new/{{item.image}}" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, but in the context of using Mustache and Django templates. Here is what worked for me.

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Mustache template part of html:

```
<div class="avatar"><img alt="" src="{% verbatim %}{{ userAvatar }}{% endverbatim %}" /></div>
```

Javascript that renders the Mustache template sends the "`userAvatar`" in the following format:

```
"userAvatar" : "/static/images/avatars/" + avatarNameFromServer
```