# How to call image object declared in angularjs script

Tags: angularjs, django

I am developing a website where i used both django and angularjs. I want to know if it is possible to use the "image" object on my page after declaring it in my angularjs script as shown below.

```
<li class="media" ng-repeat="dish in menuCtrl.dishes | filter:menuCtrl.filtText"> 
    <div class="media-left media-middle"> 
        <a href="#"> 
            {% verbatim %} 
              <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dish.image}} 
           alt="Uthapizza">
            {% endverbatim %} 
        </a> 
    </div>



 var dishes = [
     {
         name:'Uthapizza',
         image: "{% static 'images/uthapizza.png' %}",
         category: 'mains'
     }
 ]
```

Comment: Did you already try it on the page/view and had issues ?

Comment: Yes I did try it but it did not work.only the name and category worked.

Comment: Are you able to share the view part on how the `img` tag is binding ?

Comment: <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthapizza">

Comment: <li class="media" ng-repeat="dish in menuCtrl.dishes | filter:menuCtrl.filtText">
                    <div class="media-left media-middle">
                        <a href="#">
                            {% verbatim %}
                            <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthapizza">
                            {% endverbatim %}         
                        </a>
                    </div>

Comment: Please update the `html` update in the question for others to try aswell. Ta.

Comment: A snippet of the html and angularjs script has been added.

Comment: This might  be of some help... http://stackoverflow.com/a/35624423/1339516

Comment: @Searching thanks for the help, however, I am not clear on what it means to add settings.Static_url

Answer (score 0):

So according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35624423/1339516) the author suggests that you declare a variable and then use it.

```
<script> 
 var MY_STATIC = '{% static %}';
   function EscapeMyUrl(path) {
     return MY_STATIC + path;
   }
 </script>
```

django will render this template on server and put the correct value against it.

In the current setup once your data reaches client, angular doesn't know what or how to render django script which is probably the issue.

script: update the object properties like so

```
image: "images/uthapizza.png"
```

html

```
<img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src="EscapeMyUrl({{dish.image}})" alt="Uthapizza">
```

Please check and let us know if this has worked and suggest any changes/fixes, so people don't end up using an incorrect answer :)